# Xcode 8 problems building with Jenkins

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jenkins, xcode8

I've just download Xcode 8, make some settings changes and try to build with Jenkins but it fails and appears this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
  CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/ujenkins/ujenkins/workspace/project-ios/XXXXX/Views/Timeline/Components/Transitions/CustomTransition.swift
  CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/ujenkins/ujenkins/workspace/project-ios/XXXXX/ProjectBase/Operations/TextViewController.swift
  CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(3 failures)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Build step 'Upload to HockeyApp' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I don't know if could be a HockeyApp problem or maybe its because Xcode 8 settings.
I'm using manual signing configuration but I dont have iOS Distribution nor iOS Development certificates.

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Is this normally (i.e. without Jenkins) build in Xcode 8?

Comment: Yes, i can build in Xcode 8 and run in simulator and device too, but not in Jenkins @AnniS

Comment: If the build of your code fails, then there is no app created and hence the upload will fail too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem and its because we have Xcode 7.3 in Jenkins, so we need to update or create an Slave with 8.0 and then we will build the app successfully via Jenkins.

Here is where I found how to do it.
http://andymolloy.net/specifying-xcode-version-for-jenkins-projects/

Answer (score 1):

I have met the similar situation:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Main/View/WRNavigationBar/WRNavigationBar.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Main/View/ESTabBar.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Voice/Model/LXSkillConversion.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Lib/VoiceLib/model/FM.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Lib/VoiceLib/LXVoiceDefine.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Lib/VoiceLib/LXSpeechSynthesizerAli.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Voice/Controller/LXSkillSettingViewController.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Device/Controller/LXDeviceViewController.swift
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Voice/Controller/LXVoiceViewController.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Voice/Controller/LXSkillSettingViewController.swift
(11 failures)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It's strange about this,because the remote master branch is build OK before.I tried to remove some of the .swift files mentioned above,for example, `FM.swift` by Xcode and push to the remote repository.And then try to build again.

But I still have this:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Voice/Controller/LXSkillSettingViewController.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwift normal armv7 /Users/ifeegoo/.jenkins/workspace/ios-bluetooth-voice-assistant/VoiceAssistant/Voice/Controller/LXSkillSettingViewController.swift
(3 failures)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

And then I try to remove `LXSkillSettingViewController.swift` by Xcode and push to the remote repository,and then I try to build again.It's OK!!! Also I try to return to the first node,and then it's OK.I think there is some configuration error before.If you have the similar situation you can try to solve the problem like this.

Comment: Did you update jenkins to use Xcode 10 or at least the same that you are using to develop?

Comment: @Norolim I'm using Jenkins 2.138.2 installed by Homebrew with Xcode 10.1 on macOS 10.14.